# Как создать собственную асинхронную процедуру в 1С?

Tags: 1с, асинхронность

В 1С есть возможность использования встроенных асинхронных вызовов с помощью описания оповещения. Мне необходимо "обернуть" несколько асинхронных вызовов в один свой, так чтобы со стороны основного кода выполнялся всего один такой вызов.

Можно ли создать свои асинхронные методы и как?

Comment: Прикрутили новые методы в 8.3.18:
https://wonderland.v8.1c.ru/blog/uluchsheniya-v-sintaksise-yazyka-1s-dlya-raboty-s-asinkhronnymi-funktsiyami/

Answer (score 5):

Доброго времени суток, платформа «1С:Предприятие 8» не дает возможности реализовывать свои асинхронные процедуры и функции. Реализовать асинхронную обработку ("обернуть"), все-таки, возможность есть, с помощью процедуры:

`ВыполнитьОбработкуОповещения(<ВыполняемоеОповещение>, <Результат>)`

Этот метод используется для того, чтобы выполнить процедуру обработчика оповещения. Чтобы указать на этот обработчик, в метод передаётся описание оповещения.

Этот метод требуется в сложных «многоуровневых» алгоритмах асинхронных вызовов, так как описание оповещения может быть сконструировано в начале алгоритма, а реальное использование этого обработчика может понадобиться через несколько вложенных процедур. Пример:

> **Вопрос во вложенной процедуре, после которой есть код**
>
> Рассмотрим более сложный случай, когда после вызова вложенной функции
>   выполнятся некоторый код. Например, так:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Казалось бы, следуя рекомендациям, надо просто заменить вложенную процедуру двумя процедурами:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Однако в этом случае алгоритм, следующий за вызовом вложенной процедуры, будет выполнен ещё до того, как пользователь ответит на вопрос. Ведь, как мы знаем, исполнение кода не останавливается после выполнения блокирующего метода ([Сравнение модального и немодального режимов работы](https://its.1c.ru/docs/v8nonmodal/#3)):
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Поэтому в такой ситуации нужно не только использовать блокирующий метод с вызовом оповещения, но ещё и выполнять асинхронный вызов самой вложенной процедуры, также используя оповещение:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Здесь во вложенную процедуру мы сразу передаём описание оповещения, в котором содержится тот код, который должен быть выполнен после вложенной процедуры (последняя процедура). Вызывая блокирующий метод, мы передаём ему «его» описание оповещения (ВложеннаяПроцедураЗавершение), а также, через дополнительные параметры, то описание оповещения, которое нужно будет выполнить после того, как будут обработаны интерактивные действия пользователя (ОбработкаКомандыЗавершение).

([Источник](https://its.1c.ru/docs/v8nonmodal/#23))

P.S. Необходимо помнить, что при работе с **синхронными вызовами** значения передаются по `Ссылке` (в синхронные процедуры и функции), а при **асинхронных вызовах** по `Значению`. Пример:

> **Вопрос в обработчике формы ПередЗакрытием**
>
> Особенность диалога с пользователем в этом (и многих других)
>   обработчиках заключается в том, что в зависимости от реакции
>   пользователя принимается решение: продолжать дальнейшие действия, или
>   отказаться от них. Для этого используется параметр процедуры Отказ.
>   При одном ответе пользователя мы отказываемся от продолжения (Отказ =
>   Истина). При другом ответе пользователя - продолжаем дальнейшие
>   действия.
>
> В данном случае сложность заключается в том, что ответ пользователя мы
>   узнаем уже после того, как выйдем из контекста этого обработчика. В
>   процедуре, обрабатывающей оповещение. А параметр Отказ нужно
>   установить именно в этом обработчике.
>
> Поэтому мы действуем в два приёма:
>
> В первый раз безусловно отменяем дальнейшие действия **(Отказ = Истина)**
>   и выводим вопрос пользователю; В обработчике оповещения, в зависимости
>   от реакции пользователя, либо снова программно закрываем форму, либо
>   ничего не делаем. Проблема заключается в том, что обработчик
>   ПередЗакрытием будет выполнен два раза. И чтобы отличить первое его
>   выполнение от второго (когда ответ пользователя уже известен) мы
>   используем клиентскую переменную ВыполняетсяЗакрытие в качестве флага.
>
> В первый проход её значение равно Ложь, и это значит, что нужно
>   отказаться от закрытия и задать вопрос. Во второй проход её значение
>   равно Истина, и это значит, что вопрос задавать не надо:
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

([Источник](https://its.1c.ru/docs/v8nonmodal/#24))

Comment: Отличный ответ! Было бы ещё лучше, если бы примеры из ссылок были бы оформлены прям в ответе. Ссылки могут устареть.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую использовать фоновые задания.

```
// Формирование рабочего листа
// Параметры;
//  Документ - ДокументСсылка - Пакетный документ
//
Процедура СформироватьРабочийЛист(Документ) Экспорт  

    Структура = Новый Структура;
    Структура.Вставить("Документ", Документ);

    ПараметрыВыполнения = Новый Массив;
    ПараметрыВыполнения.Добавить(Структура);

    ФоновыеЗадания.Выполнить("ДлительныеОперации.СформироватьРабочийЛист",
        ПараметрыВыполнения, 
        Новый УникальныйИдентификатор,
        "Автоматическое создание пакета документов для рабочего листа");

КонецПроцедуры
```

**ФоновыеЗадания** - Посмотри в сторону синтаксис помощника (Надеюсь суть понятна)

Answer (score 0):

Пример выполнения функции в фоновом задании при использовании в конфигурации Библиотеки стандартных подсистем. В модуле менеджера объекта размещена функция, которая выполняет поиск настроек и возвращает их:

```
Функция ОпределитьНастройкиУчетнойЗаписи(АдресЭлектроннойПочты, Пароль) Экспорт
 ...
 Возврат Настройки;
КонецФункции
```

В форме объекта выполняется вызов этой функции в фоновом задании в три этапа:

1. запуск фонового задания на сервере,
2. подключение обработчика завершения фонового задания на клиенте,
3. обработка результата выполнения фонового задания.

```
&НаКлиенте
Процедура НастроитьПараметрыПодключенияАвтоматически()
 // 1. Запуск фонового задания на сервере.
 ДлительнаяОперация = НачатьПоискНастроекУчетнойЗаписи();
 
 // 2. Подключение обработчика завершения фонового задания.
 ПараметрыОжидания = ДлительныеОперацииКлиент.ПараметрыОжидания(ЭтотОбъект);
 Оповещение = Новый ОписаниеОповещения("ПриЗавершенииПоискаНастроек", ЭтотОбъект);
 ДлительныеОперацииКлиент.ОжидатьЗавершение(
  ДлительнаяОперация, Оповещение, ПараметрыОжидания);
КонецПроцедуры
```

```
&НаСервере
Функция НачатьПоискНастроекУчетнойЗаписи()
 ПараметрыВыполнения = ДлительныеОперации.ПараметрыВыполненияФункции(
  УникальныйИдентификатор);
 Возврат ДлительныеОперации.ВыполнитьФункцию(
  ПараметрыВыполнения, 
  "Справочники.УчетныеЗаписиЭлектроннойПочты.ОпределитьНастройкиУчетнойЗаписи",
  АдресЭлектроннойПочты, Пароль);
КонецФункции
```

```
// 3. Обработка результата выполнения фонового задания.
&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПриЗавершенииПоискаНастроек(Результат, ДополнительныеПараметры) Экспорт

 Если Результат = Неопределено Тогда // Пользователь отменил задание.
  Возврат;
 КонецЕсли;
 
 Если Результат.Статус = "Ошибка" Тогда
  ВызватьИсключение Результат.КраткоеПредставлениеОшибки;
 КонецЕсли;
 
 Настройки = ПолучитьИзВременногоХранилища(Результат.АдресРезультата);
 УдалитьИзВременногоХранилища(Результат.АдресРезультата);
 УстановитьНастройкиУчетнойЗаписи(Настройки);
 
КонецПроцедуры
```

[Источник](https://its.1c.ru/db/v8std/content/642/hdoc)